# How to change .txt file extension to .xml file extension using regular expression?

Tags: java, jmeter

```
String FileName= vars.get(''resultspath" + "/" + vars.get("path") + "/" + props.get("") +"/" + Vars.get("Name")
```

the output file is the format of "Name.txt" I want it to change to "Name.xml" how can I change this using regular expression.

Comment: any specific reason for regex ?

Comment: No nothing specific, I am learning how to use regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use split, assuming file name doesn't contain `'.'`

```
String s ="Name.txt";
s = s.split("\\.")[0]+".xml";
```

---

Another, solution could be using `replaceAll`, in this case, it doesn't matter whether filename contains `'.'` or not.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.txt$",".xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `String changedName = fileName.replaceAll(".txt$", ".xml");`
That way, `.txt` in the end of file name will be changed to `.xml` (Note `$` after `.txt`), and it works even if the file name contains `.` somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript it would be something like this:

```
"Name.txt".replace(/\.txt$/, '.xml');
```

In Java, you can do it like this:

```
"Name.txt".replaceFirst("\\.txt$", ".xml");
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using square brackets around `\\.`? Square brackets around a single 'character' should not do anything if I am correct.

Comment: Just habit. Yes, I believe you are correct. It can be removed. I have updated the answer to reflect your comment.